# OnResume triggers button click

Tags: android, android-intent, motorola-emdk

Good day all,
Having this weird problem this morning. Working with Motorola TC55 (Android)

The TC55 has an API to trigger its inbuilt scanner. This is done via Intents. This is what i was looking for.

1. Click a button to trigger in-built scanner - this launches an intent to scan the barcode and return it back to the activity.
2. Once the data is returned, its stored into a textview and processed accordingly.

The problem, however is, when the intent returns to the activity, onResume fires(as expected), but this also fires the button's onClick event again, resulting in the scanner firing repeatedly.

Effectively my LogCat looks something like this

```
09-03 12:09:08.089: I/System.out(1128): On resume
09-03 12:09:08.810: I/System.out(1128): Scan button clicked
09-03 12:09:08.820: I/System.out(1128): On resume
09-03 12:09:09.430: I/System.out(1128): Scan button clicked
09-03 12:09:09.440: I/System.out(1128): On resume
09-03 12:09:10.091: I/System.out(1128): Scan button clicked
09-03 12:09:10.111: I/System.out(1128): On resume .......
```

Coming to the code: Any help is highly appreciated.

```
public class ScanTagActivity extends Activity {
    // Tag used for logging errors
    private static final String TAG = ScanTagActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Context ctx;
    ActionBar actionBar ;
    GlobalFunctions gF=new GlobalFunctions();
    private TextView textViewBarcode = null; 
    private Button btnImage=null;
    info.hoang8f.widget.FButton btnToggle;
    Button btnScan;
    private String profileName = "PatientTag";  //Normal 2D Scan
    private ProfileManager mProfileManager = null;
    private EMDKManager emdkManager = null;     
    ProfileConfig profileConfigObj = new ProfileConfig(); 
    Boolean isImageScanner=false;
     // Let's define the API intent strings for the soft scan trigger
    private static final String SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.ACTION_SCANNERINPUTPLUGIN";
    private static final String ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER";
    private static final String ACTION_SETPROFILE = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.ACTION_SETDEFAULTPROFILE";
    private static final String EXTRA_PARAM = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.EXTRA_PARAMETER";
    private static final String EXTRA_DATA = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.EXTRA_PROFILENAME";
    private static final String DWAPI_START_SCANNING = "START_SCANNING";
    private static final String DWAPI_STOP_SCANNING = "STOP_SCANNING";
    private static final String DWAPI_TOGGLE_SCANNING = "TOGGLE_SCANNING";

    private static String ourIntentAction = "com.veeru.labtest.RECVR";
    private static final String SOURCE_TAG = "com.veeru.labtest.source";
    private static final String DATA_STRING_TAG = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.data_string";
    private static final String LABEL_TYPE_TAG = "com.veeru.labtest.label_type";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx=this;
        getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Scan Patient Tag - 2D Code");      
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan( this,"Helvetica-Bold.otf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        setTitle(s);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_tag);
        textViewBarcode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);
        btnToggle=(info.hoang8f.widget.FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnToggleScanner);
        btnToggle.setTypeface(gF.getHelvetica(ctx, true));
        btnScan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScanB);
        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Scan button clicked");
                int triggerDelay = 250; // delay in milliseconds
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Intent i = new Intent();
                            i.setAction(SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN);
                            i.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM, "ENABLE_PLUGIN");
                            ScanTagActivity.this.sendBroadcast(i);
                            i.setAction(ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER);                            
                            i.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM, DWAPI_TOGGLE_SCANNING);
                            sendBroadcast(i);
                        }
                }, triggerDelay);

            }
        });
        //Intent i = getIntent();
        //handleDecodeData(i);


    }
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
        // set the action to perform
        handleDecodeData(i);
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onResume() {
        System.out.println("On resume");
        super.onResume();       
        Intent iResume = new Intent();
        // set the action to perform
        iResume.setAction(SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN);
        iResume.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM, "DISABLE_PLUGIN");
        sendBroadcast(iResume);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();      

    }   
    // This method is responsible for getting the data from the intent
    // formatting it and adding it to the end of the edit box
    private void handleDecodeData(Intent i) {
        // check the intent action is for us

        if ( i.getAction().contentEquals(ourIntentAction) ) {
            // define a string that will hold our output
            String out = "";
            // get the source of the data
            String source = i.getStringExtra(SOURCE_TAG);
            // save it to use later
            if (source == null) source = "scanner";
            // get the data from the intent
            String data = i.getStringExtra(DATA_STRING_TAG);
            // let's define a variable for the data length
            Integer data_len = 0;
            // and set it to the length of the data
            if (data != null) data_len = data.length();

            // check if the data has come from the barcode scanner
            if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("scanner")) {
                System.out.println("Intent triggered with data "+data);
                // check if there is anything in the data
                if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
                    // we have some data, so let's get it's symbology
                    String sLabelType = i.getStringExtra(LABEL_TYPE_TAG);
                    // check if the string is empty
                    if (sLabelType != null && sLabelType.length() > 0) {
                        // format of the label type string is LABEL-TYPE-SYMBOLOGY
                        // so let's skip the LABEL-TYPE- portion to get just the symbology
                        sLabelType = sLabelType.substring(11);
                    }
                    else {
                        // the string was empty so let's set it to "Unknown"
                        sLabelType = "Unknown";
                    }
                    // let's construct the beginning of our output string
                    out = "Source: Scanner, " + "Symbology: " + sLabelType + ", Length: " + data_len.toString() + ", Data: ...\r\n";
                    // now let's update the text in the edit box
                    textViewBarcode.setText(data);

                    System.out.println(out);     
                }
            }

            // check if the data has come from the MSR
            if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("msr")) {
                // construct the beginning of our output string
                out = "Source: MSR, Length: " + data_len.toString() + ", Data: ...\r\n"; 
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I did manage to solve the problem in hand, by adding a boolean variable and manipulating it during button click and resume. But, i would still like to know why button's click is called on resume. Never had this before.

Comment: Don't have an answer, but what's up with the delay on the button? And why does the activity hold a reference to itself (Context ctx)?

Comment: The EMDK(Motorola's Developkit) implements barcode scanning events with intents. And, when i would need to pass more than one action to an intent, they recommend a delay to allow the intent to process the actions. ctx, is just a convenience variable to hold the current activity when i need to pass it to some functions.

Comment: Uhm... Shouldn't that be a delay between broadcasts? Right now you delay for 250 ms and then send both actions at once. (or rather with a minimal delay between them)

Comment: That's true. But i have tried both methods seem to have produced the same result, with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set an onclicklistener for the button. AS should take care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

I really could not solve the problem, however what helped me was to use onTouch Listener and work with MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.

This did not trigger onClick event on resume repeatedly and kinda solved the problem.